# Why use azure APIM when I have app gateway

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I am new to azure and reading through their documentation and some online resources. While I am trying to deploy microservices on azure I can see that I can use APIM. However azure also has app gateway which seems to offer much more functionality.
So why should someone use APIM and not gateway directly? Is it only because of cost?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The opposite is true, Azure API Management offers much more functionality. However, these are two completely different services:

Azure Application Gateway is a web traffic **load balancer** that enables you to manage traffic to your web applications

Azure API Management is a **platform** that allows you to *manage* APIs in a secure and scalable way.

Further reading:

- [What is Azure Application Gateway?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/overview?WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5003203)
- [About API Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-key-concepts?WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5003203)

Answer (score 2):

This is a supplement for APIM: APIM provides a way to commercialize your APIs, you can charge your API users by subscription or calling Meteres. Details see: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/how-to-monetize-apis-with-azure-api-management/